# In Golang, how do I define a specific sort of map as a unique type?

Tags: templates, go, datacontext, custom-type

So I'm at that awkward place where I'm trying to pass context data over to a template, and there's not a whole lot of really great examples out there that don't involve passing a preexisting structure.  The best I have come up with is something like the following:

```
templ.Execute(writer, map[string]interface{}{
    "thingyA": ThingyA,
    "thingyB": ThingyB,
})
```

Using the above, I can reference `ThingyA` and all of its properties and methods in my template by using `{{ .thingyA.[PROPERTY] }}`.  So that's pretty good in itself, in that it allows me to define a context in a simple Django-ish fashion, without using an anonymous struct, which would be a bit clunky.

But I'm wondering if there is some way to define a new type `Context`, so that I could simplify the above to the following:

```
templ.Execute(writer, Context{
    "thingyA": ThingyA,
    "thingyB": ThingyB,
})
```

That is, I would like to define a specific type `Context` that always has the form `map[string]interface{}`, and can be initialized in the same manner as a map. Any ideas on how to go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
type Context map[string]interface{}
c := Context{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/EbfIFg-4cy).